# Can't install tensor flow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, dll, pycharm

I wanted to install tensor flow to work on a ML project. I have python 3.7.9 64 bit version. I first installed the latest version of tensor flow but got the error: "ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: [https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads"](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads%22)
I downloaded the msvcp140 and msvcp140_1 DLLs included them into my python37 directory, went to the recommended website downloaded the .rar packages and installed them as they asked me to do.
I tried several python version and I have also tried different tensorflow versions and nothing helps unfortunately. I need a fast solution since I've been working on the issue for 2 days now and I'm really about to lose my mind.

Comment: What exact exe files you installed from the microsoft site?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution can be to use tensorflow in a docker container. A guide on how to do this can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker).

The advantage of using docker is that you don't have to set up all the dependancies. You just have to pull the docker image from the docker hub and you can get it running in a minute. Even if you want to use (training)data from your local file system then you can just mount it as "volumes" in your docker container so that all training checkpoint data is saved on your local machine.